# Mock an object which created by new operator in Java without PowerMock feature

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I want to *mock* an object which is created using `new` operator in code. I dont want to use PowerMock feature. How can I achieve this?

I am using the [*strategy pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) with [*chain-of-responsibility*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern for this.

Sample code:

```
ValidationHandlerProcessor validationHandlerProcessor = new ValidationHandlerProcessor();
List<ValidationHandler> dataValidationHandlers = validationHandlerProcessor.getDataValidationHandlers();

dataValidationHandlers.add(new abcHandler());

validationHandlerProcessor.validate(componentInfoInput);
```

Comment: [My article here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) should give you some ideas.  Yes, I am the original author, even though my name doesn't appear on that page.

Comment: do you intend to mock validationHandlerProcessor

Comment: @DhruvRajSinghRathore : i want to mock validationHandlerProcessor.validate(componentInfoInput) line

Answer (score 1):

Simply spoken: you can't.

The ability to **mock** calls to **new** requires to turn to the PowerMock(ito) or JMockit frameworks.

The real answer is: rework your production code to **not** make a call to `new` here, for example by:

- using [*dependency injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to provide an instance of that other class in your class under test
- using *dependency injection* to provide a **factory** that provides instances of the class you need (and then your **factory** is a mocked thing, that returns whatever you want it to return).

Long story short: before engaging in PowerMock or other frameworks, engage in learning how to create testable code. Watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from ValidationHandlerProcessor and create a new class ValidationHandlerProcessorMock and now in this mock the validate method or whichever method you want to mock.

```
public class ValidationHandlerProcessorMock extends ValidationHandlerProcessor{

    public void validate(args){
       // write mock code here
    }

}
```

Now in test file use

```
ValidationHandlerProcessor validationHandlerProcessor = new ValidationHandlerProcessorMock();
```